# install asp.net application on IIS using wix without IIS backward compatibilty on

Tags: wix

I have created WiX installer that installs website in IIS but I have to keep IIS backward compatibility on.

```
   <Component Id="VirtualDirectoryWebAppPool" Guid="{GIUD}" Permanent="yes">
     <iis:WebAppPool Id="WebAppPool" Name="${ProductName}" ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" ManagedPipelineMode="integrated" />
     <CreateFolder />
   </Component>

   <Component Id="VirtualDirectoryWithoutWinAuth" Guid="{GUID}" Permanent="yes">
     <Condition>TYPEOFAUTHENTICATION = "Forms"</Condition>
       <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="WebVirtualDirectoryWithoutWinAuth" Alias="[VDNAME]" Directory="WEBUIFOLDER" WebSite="DefaultWebSite" >
         <iis:WebApplication Id="WebApplicationWithoutWinAuth" Name="[VDNAME]" WebAppPool="WebAppPool" />
         <iis:WebDirProperties Id="WebDirectoryPropertiesWithoutWinAuth" AnonymousAccess="yes" WindowsAuthentication="no" />
       </iis:WebVirtualDir>
       <CreateFolder />
    </Component>

    <Component Id="VirtualDirectoryWithWinAuth" Guid="{GIUD}" Permanent="yes">
      <Condition>TYPEOFAUTHENTICATION = "Windows"</Condition>
      <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="WebVirtualDirectoryWithWinAuth" Alias="[VDNAME]" Directory="WEBUIFOLDER" WebSite="DefaultWebSite" >
        <iis:WebApplication Id="WebApplicationWithWinAuth" Name="[VDNAME]" WebAppPool="WebAppPool" />
        <iis:WebDirProperties Id="WebDirectoryPropertiesWithWinAuth" AnonymousAccess="yes" WindowsAuthentication="yes" />
      </iis:WebVirtualDir>
      <CreateFolder />
    </Component>

...

<iis:WebSite Id="DefaultWebSite" Description="Default Web Site" Directory="WEBUIFOLDER">
  <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="80" />
</iis:WebSite>
```

But I do not want to keep the IIS backward compatibility on.

Comment: Starting from WiX 3.5, you don't have to keep IIS 6 compatibility on, since that version of WiX natively supports IIS 7: http://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/60102

Comment: ok. and for Windows 8 ?? do I need to make any changes or move to higher version of wix

Comment: That is will my installer created in wix 3.5 run on windows 8 and install website in IIS 8?

Comment: Same for Windows 8 and IIS8. Just try it out with pure WiX 3.5 or higher. Actually, it's recommended to grab the most recent stable release, if that's a fresh project